# Connect to SqlServer using windows credentials

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I got a MVC app where I should use Windows Credentials when connecting to a Sql Server.

I do not want to run the AppPool with those credentials, is it possible to do it in another way? Or are the preferred way to let the application pool run using the credentials needed to connect to sql server?

***Edit***

To elaborate a bit:

We are using ASP.NET impersonation / windows authentication for security in the IIS applications. That makes it a bit hard to use the proper windows account when connecting to the database. Do we have to switch to sql authentication or use custom impersonation (win apis) wrapped around the database handling? Are there any other ways?

Comment: Why you not use the Integrated Security? Is this a problem? After using this in connection string, you need to configure IIS app to allow login with windows credentials.

Comment: Because ASP.Net impersonation is ON and it's not the logged in user's account that has access to the database.

Comment: If using Windows credentials to connect to a SQL server, and if not using integrated security, how do you plan to authenticate the user's password with SQL Server? Will you have access to the user's Windows account password in order to pass to SQL Server?

Comment: Windows authentication in SQL Server always authenticates using the credentials of the current logged in Windows user...Perhaps a kludge might be "create a SQL Server user account for each Windows user and log in with that user's account using SQL Server authentication" kind of thing, but that is not the same thing as your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx) which covers the scenarios of credential impersonation (SQL server on the same machine as the web server) and delegation (SQL server on a different machine than the web server). Delegation could be PITA to setup so using SQL authentication is probably the easiest way to go.